# Python won't let me use variable inside function

Tags: python, variables, pygame, global, local

I don't understand why it won't let me use display_w or display_h inside of the function. I can't have it inside the function because I don't want it to reset when I use it again. How can I allow it to use those variables?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_w = 800
display_h = 600

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
grey = (100, 100, 100)


def run():

    print("Input your message: ")
    msg = input()

    print("Enter font size: ")
    font_size = int(input())

    display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_w, display_h))
    pygame.display.set_caption("TextPos")

    text_x = 0
    text_y = 0

    def message_to_screen(msg, color, font_size, x, y):

        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, font_size)
        screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
        display.blit(screen_text, [x, y])
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    running = False
                    pygame.quit()
                    run()
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:

                    print("Enter display width: ")
                    display_w = int(input())

                    print("Enter display height: ")
                    display_h = int(input())
                    running = False

            message_to_screen(msg, (255, 255, 255), 50, text_x, text_y)
            m_x, m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            text_x = m_x
            text_y = m_y

            display.fill(white)
            message_to_screen("X: %s" % m_x, black, 30, 10, 10)
            message_to_screen("Y: %s" % m_y, black, 30, 10, 30)
            message_to_screen(msg, black, font_size, text_x, text_y)
            message_to_screen("Press Q to Change Screen Size", grey, 30, display_w - 310, 0)
            message_to_screen("Press R to Restart", grey, 30, display_w - 180, 30)

            pygame.display.update()
run()
```

Comment: What is your question? What error are you encountering?

Answer (score 1):

Add them as parameters?

```
def run(display_w, display_h):
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python:

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.
>
> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains this. On one hand, requiring global for assigned variables provides a bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if global was required for all global references, you’d be using global all the time. You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would defeat the usefulness of the global declaration for identifying side-effects.

In your case, you are attempting to set variables in your function, so Python treats them as local variables.

To treat them as global variables, use the `global` keyword when you locally define them to indicate you're referencing, and modifying, the values outside the function scope.

Answer (score 1):

A strange way of accessing the variable. Let's say your module name is xyz. Then:

```
import xyz

def func():
    xyz.display_w = 80
```